# Store random generated string as variable and pass it to input text using selenium2library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

Can someone tell me what is wrong in the following code.I am trying to input text with random generated string . It works fine when i use without selenium2library . Any help would be appreciated.

```
Keywords.txt

***Settings***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library     String


*** Variables ***

${URL}                  https://www.google.co.in/
${Browser}              Chrome
${RandomString}         Generate Random String    10    [LETTERS]

*** Keywords ***

Google Input Random String
    Open Browser    ${URL}      ${Browser}
    Input Text      //*[@id='lst-ib']   ${RandomString}
    Close Browser

Execute.txt

*** settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Resource          Google_Test_Keywords.txt


*** Test Cases ***


Google Random String Search
    Google Input Random String
```

Comment: Madhu, if my solution suits you, please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use keywords in variable definition block (`*** Variables ***`).

Instead, populate random variables either inside your keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***
Google Input Random String
    ${RandomString}=         Generate Random String    10    [LETTERS]
    Open Browser    ${URL}      ${Browser}
    Input Text      //*[@id='lst-ib']   ${RandomString}
    Close Browser
```

Or as a part of the test case:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Google Random String Search
    ${RandomString}=         Generate Random String    10    [LETTERS]
    Google Input  ${RandomString}
```

You can also use [setups](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown).

Comment: I suggest changing "_should not_" with _"cannot"_ (ie: "you _cannot_ use keywords in variable definition block".